# how to generate the array contains random number in ascending order using java

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to make the array contains random number in ascending order, for example (1,5,10...100), but not (5,1,10...).
this code but when run the number not be ascending . what the error?

````
     Random r=new Random();
     int t=10;
       int a[]=new int[t];
     int count=0;
     int end=0;
     int curr=0;
     while(count<t){
     curr=r.nextInt();
     end=end+curr;
     count++;}
     for(int i=0;i<to;i++){
     a[i]=r.nextInt(10);}
 ```
````

Comment: Maybe something like this? https://ideone.com/vtKJHf where you save the previously generated value to be used to generate the next one, only downside is, when random value generated is pretty high, as seen in the link...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Random#ints` method which returns a stream of random int values. Assuming you want 10 random ints from the range `[1,100)` sorted in ascending order:

```
Random r = new Random();
int t    = 10;
int a[]  = r.ints(1, 100).distinct().limit(t).sorted().toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

you can omit `distinct` if you want to allow duplicates

To sort in descending order you need to box the primitiv types to Integer and use `Comparator.reverseOrder()` or `Collections.reverseOrder()` and unbox them after sorting to store them in an int array

```
int a[]  = r.ints(0, 100)
                .distinct()
                .limit(t)
                .boxed()
                .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                .toArray();
```

Comment: @Maymunah Edited.